# Unable to build onesignal flutter in ios simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, notifications, simulator, onesignal

Hi actually I open the question in https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/731, so I am trying to install onesignal in my flutter project, actually I don't use it in ios, I only use it in android. There were nothing wrong when I do debugging in android and try all of the functions are fine. But when I try to debug in simulator it always build success (xcode build done) but nothing happen (apk doesn't launch). So I try to build it from Xcode, apk build success (but that's only white screen and I get log like this below. For additional information, although I don't use onesignal for ios (for now, maybe later) I still follow the configuration step by step from the documentation (like: adding configuration in podfile n xcode (OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension)

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes
  Referenced from: <CF59B0E8-635A-39BE-B861-E005A88B49A4> /Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhlxakmdkfjsdeebtbxarwjvblbf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2)
Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes
  Referenced from: <CF59B0E8-635A-39BE-B861-E005A88B49A4> /Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE7B5F40-22D0-40A0-A05E-8B9BEB3FC037/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/09B4A3F6-FB5B-4C01-8139-51FB1AD70204/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhlxakmdkfjsdeebtbxarwjvblbf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swi
dyld config: DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/22G90/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2.20C52 DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhlxakmdkfjsdeebtbxarwjvblbf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/usr/lib/libRPAC.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/umsi06/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhlxakmdkfjsdeebtbxarwjvblbf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib
```

is there a way to solve this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi finally I solve my case by following this step : https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/1459#issuecomment-1383149854 , I manually add OneSignalOutcomes